# docker compose down specific profile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I try to docker compose down specific profile, it stops and removes all container.
I want to remove only containers that are in referred profile.

```sh
docker compose --profile elk down         # Let's say I have some services in elk profile
```

In above example I wanted to bring down only services that are tagged with `elk` profile.

Answer (score 3):

Using docker compose 2.16.0, I got it working by pointing the docker compose file :

```
docker compose -f my-compose-file.yaml --profile my-profile down
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.  I am using Docker Compose version v2.22.0-desktop.2.  My use case is I have a mongodb service and I have an admin profile that I sometimes enable.  I can use compose up with the admin profile and it works fine.  But when I use compose down it nukes everything.  I tried using the -f file but same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here (not really an answer). Alternatively it would be great to have `docker compose --profile foo up --remove-orphans` or similar also working.

There was a similar issue about it but it literally just got closed due to inactivity:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8432

Answer (score 0):

We have been experiencing the same issues. I followed the [thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8139) on the bug report. It looks like it was not solved yet.

We moved from using compose to swarm (multiple 1 node manager clusters instead of only using compose). And since now we use stacks we don't need profiles anymore.